# new URL().openSteam() method returns null when passed to ImageIO

Tags: java, scala, image-processing, javax.imageio

Currently trying to pass an `InputSteam` to Java's `ImageIO` by providing a `URL().openStream()`.

```
val sourceIO = new URL(fileName).openStream()
val bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(sourceIO)
```

I am testing around 100 different images. I know each image exists because when I pass the same input steam to a different class, it works just fine. However, ImageIO keeps complaining the stream is null: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!`

My suspicion is that something is not properly initializing. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the problem. It actually was because I was using a `val sourceIO` assuming the input stream was re-usable. By changing `val` to `def` I was able to pass a fresh input stream to the ImageIO object.

Note: this wasn't working properly because `sourceIO` was already referenced before it was passed to `ImageIO`, thus the stream was null.